# Konsole does not have permission to save this profile to /home/aravindakrishnan/.local/share/konsole/Profile 2.profile

Tags: terminal, kde, profile

I'm using KDE Neon on Debian. When I'm trying to change my profile It says *Konsole does not have permission to save this profile to /home/username/.local/share/Konsole/Profile 2.profile*:

[image: screenshot of the error]

```
ls -l /home/aravindakrishnan/.local/share/konsole/Profile*

-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 1645 May  5 18:56 '/home/aravindakrishnan/.local/share/konsole/Profil

ls -ld  /home/aravindakrishnan/.local/share/konsole/ /home/aravindakrishnan/.local/share/ /home/aravindakrishnan/.local/

drwxrwxr-x  5 mongodb mongodb 4096 May  5 19:15 /home/aravindakrishnan/.local/
drwxrwxr-x 37 mongodb mongodb 4096 Jun 28 11:14 /home/aravindakrishnan/.local/share/
drwxrwxr-x  2 mongodb mongodb 4096 May  5 18:56 /home/aravindakrishnan/.lo
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -l /home/username/.local/share/Konsole/Profile*` and `ls -ld  /home/username/.local/share/Konsole/ /home/username/.local/share/ /home/username/.local/`

Comment: I added that output

Comment: It is *KDE* on Debian. KDE Neon is a distro by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the file you are trying to write to is owned by another user: `mongodb`. Looks like you logged in as the MongoDB user for some reason and ran GUI applications. The fix is to change the ownership back to *your* user:

```
sudo chown -R aravindakrishnan:aravindakrishnan /home/aravindakrishnan/.local
```

You should also have a look at other directories and files in your home, all of those should be owned by your user, so you might want to just run:

```
sudo chown -R aravindakrishnan:aravindakrishnan ~/
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the .profile files are located in `/usr/share/konsole`

So I did,

`cd /usr/share/konsole && sudo chmod -R a+rwX *`

That did it.
But it makes it available to all users.

Comment: They are the defaults [read-only], when you edit them they are written to `~/.local/share/konsole/profile`. No need changing permission.

Comment: In my case the profile folder is empty so I needed a workaround